# My computer dose not recognise my Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I had never used Arduino before. When I tried to interface my new Arduino Uno board to my computer, the computer failed to recognize the board.

Why isn't the board interfaced successfully? How should I troubleshoot that problem?

Comment: Did you install the drivers? Is it a genuine Arduino? Are you using a fully wired USB cable?

Answer (score 1):

Majenko is probably right.  If it is a clone Arduino board you will need to install some CH340 drivers.  If it's an authentic board I would return it as it should work out of the box with the Arduino IDE.

Comment: Also if you are on a Windows PC be careful because FTDI drivers have been known to kill these boards.  I've also encountered something with Windows 10 when the updated driver causes the CH340 to quit responding.  If you have access to a machine running Ubuntu these drivers come preloaded and work out of the box.